OpenRPA flow only enters one row and exits
I am complete new to OpenRPA. I am trying to fill-up simple survey responses from an excel file using RPA. For this, I wrote a flow (screenshot attached). The issue is that it only enters one row from the excel file , clicks submit and exits. This is confirmed from the fact that I can only see one response in surveymonkey profile being registered. I tried putting the "open url" block inside loop but no use.
This is excel file format.

This is the workflow -

The survey is  - here

Try adding a breakpoint (F9) and single step though the loop (F10)
My guess is, it is going though the loop multiple times, and you are just seeing the last data, but the submit button is not working ( in that case you could true to set virtual click to false on the click element )
